# Python Regex Extract Text Within HTML Tags

Tags: python, html, regex

Consider the following:

```
<div id=foodmenu>
    <a href="randomlink">Hot Dog</a>
</div>
<div id=foodmenu>
    <a href="randomlink">Burger</a>
</div>
<div id=foodmenu>
    <a href="randomlink">Chips</a>
</div>
<div id=foodmenu>
    <a href="randomlink">Coke</a>
</div>
```

How would I do this using regex to get the following printed out:

```
Hot Dog
Burger
Chips
Coke
```

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/3001761. **Use an HTML parser**, it's what they're for.

Comment: [Remove all tags](https://regex101.com/r/hX4wH7/3)

Comment: @Shafizadeh Interest, I would never have though of that. Capture everything **but** the data you need!

Answer (score 2):

**Do not parse HTML with RegEx**, but if you insist:

```
<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

The data is stored in **Capture Group #1**

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/eV9cF0/1)</kbd>

---

If the data between the `<a>` tag is on a separate line and / or includes indentation, use this RegEx:

```
<a[^>]*>\s*((?:.|\n)*?)</a>
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/tF5mO5/1)</kbd>

Comment: How would i do this without regex then?

Comment: @Anonymous Use a **HTML Parser**!

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex, HTML-parser based approach (using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) HTML parser):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div id=foodmenu>
    <a href="randomlink">Hot Dog</a>
</div>
<div id=foodmenu>
    <a href="randomlink">Burger</a>
</div>
<div id=foodmenu>
    <a href="randomlink">Chips</a>
</div>
<div id=foodmenu>
    <a href="randomlink">Coke</a>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
print([link.get_text() for link in soup.select("#foodmenu > a")])
```

Prints:

```
['Hot Dog', 'Burger', 'Chips', 'Coke']
```